# Using Condition Variables for Asynchronous Execution.

Tags: c, multithreading, asynchronous, pthreads, mutex

So I'm creating a drone simulation with Pthreads and Ncurses, I can have my code work perfectly for any number of threads synchronously, simply using a Mutex to serialize the updating of my screen. However I want to create an asynchronous simulation. Right now I'm trying to use the POSIX condvar. The idea is to the synchronize the threads on movement. So say I want to move 10 threads in 10 positions in the x direction. I want Thread1 to move one unit in the X direction, then give Thread2 the ability to move in the x-direction and so on. This is just my code for handling the creation of the pthreads and attempting synchronization:

```
int init_threads()
{
int rc = 0; int i = 0; long t = 0;
pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];

pthread_mutex_init(&mutex_lock, NULL);
pthread_cond_init(&count_threshold_cv, NULL); 

for(i; i < 2; i++) 
{
    rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, DCAS, (void *)t); 
    if(rc)
    {
        printf("Error return from create is %d\n", rc); 
        return -1; 
    }
}       
pthread_exit(NULL); 
}


void * DCAS(void * PID)
{
Tuple win = find_window(); 
int start_x = win.a/2; int start_y = win.b/2; 

pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_lock); 
while(start_x != 10)
{
    pthread_cond_wait(&count_threshold_cv, &mutex_lock); 
}

update_screen(); 

pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_lock); 
}

void update_screen()
{
Tuple win = find_window(); 
int start_x = win.a/2; int start_y = win.b/2; 

pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_lock); 

mvwaddch(local_win, start_x, start_y, 'o'); 
init_base_layouts(); 
wrefresh(local_win); 
sleep(1); 
start_x--; 

pthread_cond_signal(&count_threshold_cv); 
pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_lock); 

}
```

It is exactly creating two pthreads and attempting to signal the cond-var when a thread is moved to allow another thread the ability to move in the same x-direction for 10 x positions. I cant seem to get the condition to signal that the thread has moved however. Thanks so much in advanced!

Comment: `while(start_x != 10)`. If that is false how is it ever supposed to become true? That is, that code sure looks like it is a recipe for an infinite loop.

Comment: Note that by default, a pthread mutex isn't recursive, so `update_screen()` being called from `DCAS()` will deadlock when trying to lock `mutex_lock` a second time.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts upon receiving an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wait on a condition variable, you must be waiting for some particular condition over some shared state to change (that's why it's called a condition variable).

However, the condition you are waiting on (`while (start_x != 10)`) is not over shared state: `start_x` is a local variable to each thread, which is not shared.

It's not clear exactly what state you want to wait for: however, if what you want is for each thread to move once and then not move again until all the other threads have had a chance to move, then a pthread barrier might be the appropriate primitive.

In the main function, before the threads are created:

`pthread_barrier_init(&barrier, NULL, NUM_THREADS);`

(where `NUM_THREADS` is the number of moving threads that are to be created).  Then in each moving thread:

```
for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    move();
    pthread_barrier_wait(&barrier);
}
```

All the threads will then move once (in an unspecified order), and then not continue until all other threads have moved as well.